# Не работает функция mail() php

Tags: php

Создал форму и прикрутил к ней простейший пхп код для отправки ее себе на ящик. Но она почему-то не работает. Ниже ссылка на код. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

```
<form id="calc" method="post" action="mail.php">
            <input type="email" id="email">
            <input type="number" value="some text" id="dist" class="calc-form" >
            <input type="number" value="some text" id="sqr" class="calc-form" > 
            <input type="number" value="some text" id="floor" class="calc-form"> 
            <input type="number" value="some text" id="sqrt" class="calc-form" >    
            <input type="number" value="some text" id="rad" class="calc-form" > 
            <input type="number" value="some text" id="kot" class="calc-form" >     
            <input type="number" value="some text" id="dot" class="calc-form" >     
         <span></span>
         <button type="submit" onclick="someFunc()";>ыфвывы</button>
         </form>
```

Содержимое файла mail.php

```
<?php
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if($post) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $dist = $_POST['dist'];
    $sqr = $_POST['sqr'];
    $floor = $_POST['floor'];
    $sqrt = $_POST["sqrt"];
    $rad = $_POST['rad'];
    $kot = $_POST['kot'];
    $dot = $_POST['dot'];;
    mail('jon4eg04@yandex.ru', 'сообщение с сайта', $email."\n".$dist."\n".$rad);   
}
?>
```

```
var b
var value;      
function someFunc(){
    var sqr = document.getElementById("sqr").value;
    var sqrr = sqr/10;
    sqrr = Math.ceil(sqrr);
    var floor = document.getElementById("floor").value;
    var sqrt = document.getElementById("sqrt").value;
    var one=1;
    if (sqrt>=one) {var plus=10000;}
    else {var plus=0;}
    var rad = document.getElementById("rad").value;
    var kot = document.getElementById("kot").value;
    var dot = document.getElementById("dot").value;
    var result = sqrr*1600+sqrt*300+rad*1800+kot*10000+plus+dot*2000;
    alert (result);
}
```

http://pastie.org/10731332

Comment: с чего вы взяли, что не работает? Какие ошибки в лога? Про черный список и спам листы слышали? POSTFIX? DKIM и SPF?

Comment: и приведите код функции на JS – someFunc()

Comment: А где найти логи?

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте id в форме на name везде. Ну и вообще хватило бы одного var_dump перед условием в коде + одно echo в условии, чтобы сразу отпало куча вариантов для гаданий.

update: раз у вас js код работает с этими id, значит просто продублируйте еще и name атрибут: `id="dist" name="dist"`и т.д.

Comment: поменял все id на name, никаких изменений

Comment: значит теперь вписывайте пару echo/var_dump в принимающем скрипте и смотрите что там в $_POST и заходим ли в if вообще. и вот после всего этого можно отправляться читать логи...

Comment: А можно чуток подробнее?

Comment: я уже за вас на локалке даже проверил со скуки, все там работает при вписывании name, до mail() должно доходить. впишите в if echo $email, тем самым убедившись, что при сабмите формы вы а) попадаете в это условие б) email адрес действително из ввода подхватывается

Comment: в общем если все еще не работает, значит дело таки в mail(), а т.к. вы упомянули про не-линус, то не вижу в этом ничего удивительного, что за среда в кач-ве сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите логи php, сервера. Скорее всего, просто не отправляет сервер.

В коде ошибок не нашел.

Comment: а где найти эти логи?

Comment: @jon4eg Если Linux: /var/log/

Comment: господа, в форме нет ниодного инпута с name, какие логи вы там ищите?